# Highlighting symbols automatically in Emacs

Tags: emacs, highlight, symbols

I am looking for a way to highlight symbols automatically, possibly using the package `highlight-symbol.el` ([link](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightSymbol)).

I was wondering, is there a way so that, the first argument of all `(setq )` will get automatically highlighted?

(setq **thisshouldbehighlighted** 1)

..and all the subsequent times when that symbol has been used / will be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the following code is based on [version 1.2](https://github.com/nschum/highlight-symbol.el) of highlight-symbol. Older versions lack the function `highlight-symbol-add-symbol`.

The basic approach is to search the buffer for "(setq ". The actual regular expression is a bit more complex, as it allows whitespace and handles `defvar` and `defcustom`.

```
(defun highlight-all-symbols ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (highlight-symbol-mode 1)
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (re-search-forward (concat "([ \t\n]*"
                                      "\\_<\\(?:"
                                      "setq\\|defvar\\|defcustom"
                                      "\\)\\_>[ \t\n]*"
                                      "\\(\\_<\\(?:\\sw\\|\\s_\\)+\\_>\\)")
                              nil t)
      (highlight-symbol-add-symbol (concat "\\_<"
                                           (regexp-quote (match-string 1))
                                           "\\_>")))))
```

You'll probably want to include the code in a [mode hook](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ModeHooks)

```
 (add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'highlight-all-symbols)
```

Of course, simply highlighting all symbols set with `setq` can't be a perfect solution, as it ignores variable namespaces. Handling this correctly is a much bigger task, though, as it requires parsing the code. If you want to go down that rabbit hole, [this](https://github.com/nschum/company/blob/master/company-elisp.el) might give you an idea, but I'm afraid it's not particularly documented.